# Find the remainder $1690^{2608} + 2608^{1690}$ when divided by 7?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, congruence-relations

Find the remainder $1690^{2608} + 2608^{1690}$ when divided by 7?

---

**My approach:-**

$1690 \equiv 3(\bmod 7)$

$1690^{2} \equiv 2(\bmod 7)$

$1690^{3} \equiv-1 \quad(\mathrm{mod} 7)$[ *quite easy to determine , $\frac{2*1690}{7}$..so on*]

$\left(1690^{3}\right)^{869} \cdot 1690 \equiv(-1)^{869}1690 \quad(\mathrm{mod} 7)$

$1690^{2608} \equiv -1690 \quad(\mathrm{mod} 7)$....(1)

again for $2608$

$2608 \equiv 4(\bmod 7)$

$2608^{2} \equiv 2(\bmod 7)$

$2608^{3} \equiv1 \quad(\mathrm{mod} 7)$[ *quite easy to determine , $\frac{2*2608}{7}$..so on*]

$\left(2608^{3}\right)^{563} \cdot 2608 \equiv(1)^{563}2608 \quad(\mathrm{mod} 7)$

$2608^{1690} \equiv 2608 \quad(\mathrm{mod} 7)$...(2)

**Now applying property**

adding (1) + (2),

$1690^{2608} + 2608^{1690}=918 \quad(\mathrm{mod} 7)$

$\boxed{1690^{2608} + 2608^{1690} \equiv 1 \quad(\mathrm{mod} 7)}$

**Is my approach best? or Anyother approach is there comparatively better than it**

Comment: I don't see a question.  Are you asking whether you have arrived at a correct result?

Comment: see the tag! ..sol verification.Although I have edited

Comment: Once you know $1690\equiv 3\pmod7$ then $1690^3\equiv 3^3\equiv-1\pmod7$

Comment: To shorten the steps you could have used Fermat's little theorem to get $1690^6 \equiv 1 \pmod{7}$ and $2608^6 \equiv 1 \pmod{7}$.

Comment: yes @AnuragA. good suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems fine. Try to use smaller number as fast as you can.

Using Fermat's little theorem,

$$1690^{2608}\equiv 3^{2608}\equiv 3^{6(434)+4} \equiv 3^4 \pmod{7}$$

$$2608^{1690}\equiv 4^{6(281)+4}\equiv 4^4 \pmod{7}$$

$$3^4+4^4 \equiv (-4)^4+4^4 \equiv 2(4^4) \equiv 2^9 \equiv 2^3 \equiv 1 \pmod{7}$$

Remark:

Also, I notice the way you compute $1690^3 \pmod{7}$ is by multiplying $2$ with $1690$ and then get the remainder when you divide by $7$. You don't have to do that. To compute $1690^3$, just multiply $2$ and $3$ and you get $6$ directly. That is once you figure out that $1690 \equiv 3\pmod{n}$, we know that $1690^n \equiv 3^n \mod{7}$, work with $3$ rather than $1690$. In fact, for prime $p$, $gcd(a,p)=1$, $a^n \equiv(a\pmod{p})^{(n \pmod{(p-1)})}\pmod{p}$ can reduce the magnitude of the number that you have to work wth.

Comment: but when it will be given divisible by 12 or like that, den I have to approach differently

Comment: We can use [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem) which is a generalization of Fermat's little theorem. Rather than $p-1$ use the tontient function instead. For $12$, $\phi(12) = 12\left(1-\frac12 \right)\left(1 - \frac13\right)=4$ instead.

Comment: $a^n \equiv(a\pmod{p})^{(n \pmod{(p-1)})}\pmod{p}$ .i guess it is only valid for prime no. Definitely it will decrease the volume half of my work.Thanks  a lot!

Comment: More generally, $a^n \equiv (a \pmod{m})^{(n \pmod{\phi(m))}} \pmod{m}$ using Euler's theorem.

Comment: Thanks a lot brother

Answer (score 0):

A shorter way would be to use Fermat's little theorem, plus the fact that $1690 = 7k+3$ and $2608 = 7k-3$
$$1690^6 \equiv 1 \text{   (mod 7)} \implies 1690^{2608} \equiv 1690^4 \text{ (mod 7)} \equiv 3^4 \text{(mod 7)} \equiv 4 \text{(mod 7)}$$
Similarily,
$$2608^6 \equiv 1 \text{   (mod 7)} \implies 2608^{1690} \equiv 2608^4 \text{ (mod 7)} \equiv 3^4 \text{(mod 7)} \equiv 4 \text{ (mod 7)}$$
Adding the remainders, $4 + 4 \text{  (mod 7)} \equiv 1 \text{  (mod 7)}$